# Sum of Complex Number Series

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm stuck on half of this question and was wondering if I could get a hint into what I have to do in this question.
First part: Prove that:
$$1+\operatorname{cis}{\theta}=2\operatorname{cos}\left({\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)\operatorname{cis}\left({\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)$$
I have managed to complete this part of the question. But I am confused over what to do for the second part: Hence determine the sum of the series:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r}\cos(r\theta)$$
Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: You can use this identity to write $\cos$ in terms of $\operatorname{cis}$, and then use De Moivre's theorem.

Comment: I'm confused on the combination at the front though?

Comment: The combination in the front will arise in a binomial expansion (try to think about $(x+1)^n$ binomial expansion or something similar).

Comment: Ok, so in this case, I should think about what $(1+\operatorname{cis}{\theta})^n$ means and somehow use that to find the sum?

Comment: Exactly. You should be thinking along those lines.

Comment: You are welcome.